# (R Studio)How to convert dataframe to Matrix?

Tags: r

I have a dataset, it is a data frame format.

But I need to convert to the matrix for recommender system purpose.

my data format:

```
col1    col1    col3
1      name 1   5.9 
2      name 1   7.9
3      name 1   10
4      name 1   9
5      name 1   8.4
1      name 2   6 
2      name 2   8.5
3      name 2   10
4      name 2   9.3
```

This is what I want:

```
     name 1    name 2     
1     5.9        6
2     7.9        8.5
3     10         10
4     9          9.3
5     8.4        NA (missing value, autofill "NA")
```

Comment: Can you share some data with us? That will help. Use a command like this: dput(df[1:10, 1:5] ) You will need to replace df with the name of your dataset; the command will the print a command that replicates the first ten rows and first five columns of your data. Make adjustments as needed. Copy the output and put it in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the data you shared, the following base R solution works (as long as your data frame is called `df`

```r
do.call(cbind, lapply(split(df$Hotel_Rating, df$Hotel_Name), `[`, 
                      seq(max(table(df$Hotel_Name)))))
```

Comment: If the Hotel_Rating is factor, not 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
How should let row name same as my factor variable name?
such as col1:
ZOO
BUS
COFFEE
...
...